# Laravel: HasMany relation on a pivot model

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

I'm creating a web application, which involves a system to order pizzas. I'm struggling to figure out, how to create the proper relation in the following case:

Every pizza is represented using the `Pizza` model, which has number, name, price and toppings.

In order to add extra toppings to a pizza, every topping is represented as `Pizzaextra`, which has name and price.

Every order uses the model `Pizzaorder`

`Pizzaorder` has a many-to-many relationsship to `Pizza` with pivot: quantity and comment.
I want the pivot between these two models to have a has-many relationship to `Pizzaextra`. So that every "line" in an order can have `Pizzaextra`.

How do I define this relation using Eloquent? I've been looking at custom pivot models, however I can't find a good example and the documentation is lacking on this part.

Comment: Shouldn't `Pizzaorder` and `Pizza` be a one to many?  The same pizza can't belong to many orders?  And I believe the `Pizza` and `Pizzaextra` should have a many-to-many relationship that should have nothing to do with the `Pizzaorder`.

Comment: No `Pizza` describes a pizza and it can belong to many `Pizzaorder`s and every `Pizzaorder` can have multiple `Pizza`s. `Pizzaextra` is specific to one `Pizza` of an `Pizzaorder`. I don't know how else to describe it.